# R, filter one dataset by several columns in another

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two dataframes:

```
    df1<-structure(list(record_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 
17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51), fracture_pattern___1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern___2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), fracture_pattern___3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), fracture_pattern___4 = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), fracture_pattern___5 = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_radiology___1 = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_radiology___2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_radiology___3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_radiology___4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_radiology___5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_attending___1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_attending___2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_attending___3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_attending___4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture_pattern_attending___5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and

```
df2<-structure(list(record_id = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51), Pattern = c("Lefort1", "Lefort2", "Lefort3", "NOE", 
"ZMC", "Lefort1", "Lefort2", "Lefort3", "NOE", "ZMC", "Lefort1", 
"Lefort2", "Lefort3", "NOE", "ZMC", "Lefort1", "Lefort2", "Lefort3", 
"NOE", "ZMC", "Lefort1", "Lefort2", "Lefort3", "NOE", "ZMC", 
"Lefort1", "Lefort2", "Lefort3", "NOE", "ZMC"), PlasticsSame = c("Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes"), RadiologySame = c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I want to do is check several columns in df1, and if all of them are zero in the same row, I want to delete a row from df2.

One specific instance (although I'll do this several times with several different variables) is:

- If fracture_pattern___1, fracture_pattern_radiology___1, and fracture_pattern_attending___1 are all zero's in the row for someone (like record id 51 pictured)

[image]

Then the row for "Lefort 1" (Lefort 1 is the full name for 'pattern 1' from the previous column names) would get deleted for the row for record ID 51 in df2 (leaving the other "51" rows alone)

[image]

So to reiterate what I want:   I'd be able to name 3 columns in df1, and name a value those columns correspond with, and R would find instances where all 3 columns were zero's in the same row and delete a row in df2 that had that value and the same record id where the zero's were found.

**Edited for clarity:**
Perhaps a function where I type something like: "fracture_pattern_1, fracture_pattern_radiology_1,fracture_pattern_attending_1, Lefort1"  and then it finds the record id's which have zero's in those columns, and deletes that record id and that "lefort1" pattern in df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured a function would probably be the best for this.
It takes 2 arguments:

- `cols`: the columns you want to look for in `df1`
- `pattern`: the `Pattern` you're naming in `df2`

```
library(dplyr)
remover <- function(cols,pattern){
  columns <- which(colnames(df1) %in% cols)
  rows <- which(rowSums(df1[,columns], na.rm = TRUE) == 0)
  ids <- unlist(df1[rows,"record_id"])
  df2 %>% slice(-which(record_id %in% ids & Pattern == pattern))
}
df_new <- remover(c("fracture_pattern___1","fracture_pattern_radiology___1","fracture_pattern_attending___1"),"Lefort1")

> print(df_new, n = 28)
# A tibble: 28 x 4
   record_id Pattern PlasticsSame RadiologySame
       <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        <chr>        
 1         4 Lefort1 Yes          No           
 2         4 Lefort2 No           No           
 3         4 Lefort3 Yes          Yes          
 4         4 NOE     Yes          No           
 5         4 ZMC     Yes          Yes          
 6         9 Lefort1 Yes          No           
 7         9 Lefort2 No           No           
 8         9 Lefort3 Yes          Yes          
 9         9 NOE     Yes          No           
10         9 ZMC     Yes          Yes          
11        15 Lefort1 Yes          No           
12        15 Lefort2 Yes          No           
13        15 Lefort3 Yes          No           
14        15 NOE     Yes          No           
15        15 ZMC     No           Yes          
16        17 Lefort1 Yes          Yes          
17        17 Lefort2 No           No           
18        17 Lefort3 No           Yes          
19        17 NOE     Yes          No           
20        17 ZMC     Yes          Yes          
21        51 Lefort2 Yes          Yes          
22        51 Lefort3 Yes          Yes          
23        51 NOE     Yes          No           
24        51 ZMC     Yes          Yes          
25        51 Lefort2 Yes          Yes          
26        51 Lefort3 No           No           
27        51 NOE     Yes          No           
28        51 ZMC     Yes          Yes
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I think this is almost perfect but I'll edit the question.  So I won't know the record ID I'm looking for ahead of time.  I would know the columns and the pattern name (like lefort1), but I was hoping R would look for instances where there were zero's in all three of those columns that I put in, and then find associated record ids from df1 in df2 and delete them.  Like if I typed "df_new <- remover(c("fracture_pattern___1","fracture_pattern_radiology___1","fracture_pattern_attending___1"), "Lefort1")"    it would find out 51 was one of those people and remove it

Comment: Ok, went ahead and edited my original post. Let me know how it works!

Comment: Worked great!  On the real data!